# looking for information on a marriage that took place in russia

Tags: 20th-century, marriage-records, russia

My fathers parents where from poland,
We know they escaped to Russia (sibir?) just before WWII and got married there.
At a later time they moved to camp wegscheid near linz in Austria where my father was born.

Can anyone recommend any sites that I can search for records of their marriage?

Comment: It might be helpful to add more details, as the current timeline doesn't make sense to me. Were they Polish, Russian or German? Where in Poland? How and when did they get to Austria? Could they have been in a labour camp in Russia?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. Most of Russian archives are not digitized yet, so it's very unlikely you can just search on any particular site for such information. You can do regular archive research though. You have to know the place and time of their marriage and make a request for the marriage record to local Russian archive. You can find some basic information how to do that here for example - http://genealogy.about.com/library/authors/uckroutikhin.htm

Comment: I don't know exactly where or when they got married, so I don't see how I can use a regular archive. Not what I hoped for but thanks anyway :)